# Wrong table displayField being baked even though a name getter contained in entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is the current `displayField` being set in my table:

`$this->setDisplayField('id');`

I need it to be:

`$this->setDisplayField('name');`

However, my database table has bilingual fields instead, such as `name_en` and `name_fr`, where I use a getter to populate `name` in the entity:

```
protected $_virtual = ['name'];

protected function _getName()
{
    if (Configure::read('wetkit.lang') == 'fr'){
        return $this->_properties['name_fr'];
    } else {
        return $this->_properties['name_en'];
    }
}
```

- Should the baked table, with the virtual field in the entity, have displayField set to name during baking?
- Perhaps the getter isn't available during the table bake process to determine the displayField and defaults to `id`?
- Do I have to modify the `table.twig` file to output accordingly, depending on my structure having `name_en` and `name_fr`?

Comment: Do you have lots of these that you need to bake, or can you just change the file that results from the bake process?

Comment: We have a plugin that we use for baking and we bake bilingual sites like this, thus unfortunately need to assume frequent presence of this scenario. I could tweak the plugin's table.twig file easily. I was just wondering if it was supposed to grab it through the virtual field or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up modifying the `table.twig` file:

```
{%- set setBilingualDisplayField = false %}
{%- for bf in bilingualFields %}
    {%- if bf.name == 'name' %}
        {%- set setBilingualDisplayField = true %}
    {%- endif %}    
{%- endfor %}
{% if setBilingualDisplayField %}
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
{% else %}
        $this->setDisplayField('{{ displayField }}');
{% endif %}
```